# Faye chat application failing on web server (bluehost)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, faye

This is more of a network question , I believe. Not sure what the issue is. I have a chat application which uses faye and it runs fine on my system(rails app)
with localhost:3000 having faye mounted on it.I recently deployed this rails app onto bluehost server and when I try to use the faye client on browser ,its giving me this error:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://chat.xyz.com/faye' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

The below requests\handshakes keep on repeating.

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp3** 
GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp4**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp5**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp6**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp7**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp8**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ing%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp9**

GET ...chat.xyz.com/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmet…ng%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ext%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp10**

And the failed handshakes\requests keep on getting repeated. Seeing the same on server logs also(except the 500 message obviously). The logs dont give any error apart from these repeats

Is it because of proxy\firewall issue. I recently came across an article : 
http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers

I am not sure whether its related to blocking of requests by proxy servers.

Tried switching to secure protcol. https. Didn't help. 
I use a simple client like this:

var client = new Faye.Client('http://chat.xyz.com/faye');

Any help would be great.